# Eclipse(Android)-Program shows decimals and "E"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The program shows me the result with decimals and "E" character. 
Example : n= 35 , then when I press the calculate button, it shows me the result with decimals: 922746.0000001 I don't want any decimals I want only the main number (922746) how can i fix it?

There is other other example: when I put n =36 it shows me something wrong ( it shows me  1.4930352000000019E7 ) how can I remove the E character( I want to show the full result) and manage to get the right result?

Thanks for your help.

Here is my Java code;

```
    package com.example.fibonaccicalculator;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {
        Button btn1;
        TextView tv1;
        EditText edt1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
            btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);

            btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    double n = Double . valueOf(edt1.getText().toString());
                    double a = (1 / (Math.sqrt(5))); 
                    double b = ((1+(Math.sqrt(5)))/2); 
                    double c = ((1-(Math.sqrt(5)))/2); 
                    double i = a * ((Math.pow(b,n)) - (Math.pow(c,n)));
                    String k = String.valueOf(i);
                    tv1.setText( k );                           
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get those results is because you are using `String.valueOf()`. 
Try this instead:

```
String k = String.format("%d",(int) i);
```

or this:

```
int i = (int) f;
String k = Integer.toString(i);
```

This way you will get a converted string that contains double value without any decimals.

String.valueOf is using a formatter (check Javadoc description for Double.toString() for details on how it works). 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29 
If you need a specific representation than look at this class: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Also check this [valueOf() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_valueof.htm) tutorial to understand how `String.valueOf()` works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all trailing decimal values, you can just [typecast](http://www.studytonight.com/java/type-casting-in-java) the `double` to an `int`:

```
double val = 922746.0000001;
int noDecimals = (int) val; // this gives 922746
```

If you want to have more flexibility with rounding values,you can use the [**`BigDecimal`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class and [**`RoundingMode`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html):

```
double round(double number, int decimalPlaces) {
    if(decimalPlaces == 0) { // to remove all values after the dot
        return (int) number;
    }
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(number).setScale(decimalPlaces, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

Or you can go with the [**`Math.round()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) method and make a small helper function like:

```
double round(double number, int decimalPlaces) {
    if(decimalPlaces == 0) { // to remove all values after the dot
        return (int) number;
    }
    int format = (int) Math.pow(10.0, decimalPlaces);
    return (double) Math.round(format * number)  / format;
}
```

Sample program for the above methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double val1 = 922746.0000001;
    double val2 = 1.4930352000000019E7;
    int decimalPlaces = 0;
    System.out.println((int)round1(val1, decimalPlaces));
    System.out.println((int)round2(val1, decimalPlaces));
    System.out.println((int)round1(val2, decimalPlaces));
    System.out.println((int)round2(val2, decimalPlaces));
}
```

Output:

```
922746
922746
14930352
14930352
```